# メール送信でauthorizationエラー

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail

以前は実行できていたGASのコードから、Gmailを送信するコードをコピペして来たところ、送信エラーになりました。コードは以下の通りです。

```
function send_mail() {
  var recipient = 'recipient@example.com';
  var subject = 'foo';
  var body = 'baz\n';
  var options = { name: 'bar' };
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options);
}
```

上記の関数を実行すると、まず実行権限を与えますかという表示がおき、「許可」をクリックするのですが、以下のようなエラーになります。

> アクセスが拒否されました: : Missing access token for authorization. Request:
>   MailboxService.SendMessage。 (line 143, file "SpreadSheetCode")

line 143は

```
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options);
```

の部分です。

appsscript.jsonは以下の通りです。

```
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Tokyo",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "webapp": {
    "access": "DOMAIN",
    "executeAs": "USER_ACCESSING"
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose",
          "https://mail.google.com/",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose"]
}
```

メール発信者と受信者は、同じ組織に所属しています。

どうすればメールがエラーなく送信できるでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

**追記**
`GmailApp.sendEmail()` の代わりに `MailApp.sendEmail()` にすると動作しました。ただ以前はGmailAppでも動作していましたし、この２つの違いも分かりません。

Answer (score 1):

March 10, 2016付けの記事 [Change to Mail Service in Apps Script](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/change-to-mail-service-in-apps-script) に、

> Starting on September 13, 2016, [中略] Google Apps customer who doesn’t use Gmail, but uses Apps Script instead, can send emails through MailApp but not GmailApp.

[直訳] 2016/09/13以降、Google Appsの利用者でGmailを利用せず、代わりにApps Scriptを利用している方は、emailをMailAppを介して送る事が出来ますが、GmailAppを介しては出来ません。

との記述があります。

以前できていたというのが、2016年9月12日以前なのであれば、上記の記事が関係している可能性が高いのではないでしょうか。
記事を参考にしてGoogleのアカウントを取り、そのprimary mail addressをGmailのものにする等の設定をすれば、MailAppでもGmailAppでもメールが送れるようになるのではないかと思われます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
「できていた」のは先週のことで、かつ、Gmailを使用しているアカウントで開発を行っています。
さしあたり、MailAppで必要な処理ができるかどうか調査します。
ありがとうございました。